# PHP cURL Warning during curl_multi_add_handle

Tags: php

My PHP code

```
    $urlArray = array('http://firsturl.com', 'http://secondurl.com');
    $nodeCount = count($urlArray);
    $chContainter = array();
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    for($i = 0; $i < $nodeCount; $i++) {
        $chContainter[$i] = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($chContainter[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $urlArray[$i]);
        curl_setopt($chContainter[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($chContainter[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$chContainter[$i]);
    }
```

is generating the following warning

> Warning: (null)(): 4 is not a valid
>   cURL handle resource in Unknown on
>   line 0
>
> Warning: (null)(): 5 is not a valid
>   cURL handle resource in Unknown on
>   line 0

I did some debugging and found out the warning was generated when I try to add curl handle to the $mh.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Is this your "real" code or some simplified version for SO? If it is simplified did you test that the error still occurs with this version?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to initialize `curl_multi_init()` only after you initialized your `curl_init()` sessions, otherwise you'll get that error.

Comment: For your solution you would need to put all initialized `curl_init()` sessions in a separate array, do `curl_multi_init()` and then foreach to do `curl_multi_add_handle` on each of the handles. It seems as a very inefficient solution, basically it doesn't matter when you do `curl_multi_init` as long as it's before `curl_multi_add_handle`.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this problem on one of my own scripts. The issue was caused by URLs with unencoded spaces, for example: `http://example.com/space here/`. I resolved the issue by replacing any plain space with %20, like so: `http://example.com/space%20here/`

From other reading online, it seems like this error can occur for any reason that makes the URL inaccessible or otherwise malformed.

Answer (score 0):

In [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-add-handle.php) (see example #1) shows that `curl_multi_init()` calls after `curl_init()`.
So this should work:

```
$urlArray = array('http://firsturl.com', 'http://secondurl.com');
$nodeCount = count($urlArray);
$chContainter = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodeCount; $i++) {
    $chContainter[$i] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($chContainter[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $urlArray[$i]);
    curl_setopt($chContainter[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($chContainter[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
}

$mh = curl_multi_init();
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodeCount; $i++) {
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$chContainter[$i]);
}
```

Not very elegant, but it solved my similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just encounter this problem

my code:

```
$url = 'www.meilishuo.com';
$queue = curl_multi_init();
$ci = createCh($url);
$ciSec = createCh($url);
curl_multi_add_handle($queue, $ci);
curl_multi_add_handle($queue, $ciSec);

function createCh($url) {
    $ci = curl_init();
    /* Curl settings */
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL,1);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    return $ci;
}
```

the warning:

PHP Warning:  (null)(): 34 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  (null)(): 35 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  (null)(): 34 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  (null)(): 35 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0

fix:

I add it at finally:

```
    curl_multi_close($queue);
```

problem resolved, but I don't understand, why it resolved after I add it.

what meaning is it?

"Unknown on line 0"(the part of warning)