# Php script halts when called via async curl

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous

This is a PHP code that calls $url:

```
        $handle = curl_multi_init();
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6000);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxxx:xxxx");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIE, CookieName . "=" .Security::getSid());
        //$output = curl_exec($ch);
        //curl_close($ch);
        curl_multi_add_handle($handle, $ch);
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($handle, $active);
```

The problem:
When called via curl, the script at $url halts without any error on a line with : `print "something";`. If I take the url and open it in the browser then it works fine.

This started to happen this morning on an ubuntu 14.04 system without modifying any PHP scripts.

Note that both the caller and the $url are on htaccess (same machine, same htaccess credentials)

Comment: Can the site be called via cURL? What do you mean be *halts* ? It gets blank response? It gets no response? It gets 404? 500? What did the error log tell you?

Comment: The error log is empty. I've added manual logging in a separate file on disk - which shows the script halting at that line. At this point I will call the script in any way you might suggest as long as it is asynchronous and it works :)

Comment: No error no nothing. It just...ends :)

Comment: What do you mean by ends? If you put an `echo '1';` before **and** after the line, the second line doesn't get executed?

Comment: Exactly! I've filled the called script with writeLog("1") , writeLog("2") , etc etc and in the logs I see a "x" followed by nothing. This way I managed to pinpoint where it halts.

Comment: Have you tried enabling all errors before those lines? `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: But funny thing: if I comment out the culprit PRINT call, then it will halt either immediately before or after.

Comment: I have:  `error_reporting(E_ALL - E_NOTICE - E_STRICT - E_DEPRECATED); ini_set( "display_errors" , 1);`

Comment: I've managed to have error messages : `PHP Warning:  (null)(): 34 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0` . Where and what does that mean ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080230/php-curl-warning-during-curl-multi-add-handle ?

Comment: @Dainis : already tried those solutions without success

Comment: @DainisAbols & Catalin I'm interested and I've got to run asynchronous curl calls to scrap data from 0.6 million pages of another website where pages are constantly increasing in number on daily basis.
And dumping data row by row from each page: [My Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340172/php-improve-speed-performance-of-web-crawler-to-parse-save-0-5-million-recor)
see if you can help please, improving the efficiency. Code & CSV file are both available on this page.

Comment: I've got no solution for this yet but as my process was always triggered from the UI, i've just did the fork using ajax calls :) . Not the greatest solution, but it works in my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to call session_write_close() on the ajax-called php so the session releases thus preventing the lock.